# anonymous function in javascript error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a very basic code :

```
<a href="#" onClick="function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
 }">LogOut</a>
```

I'm not even pretty sure , if this is right or not but when i click on the link, i do see an error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

I just want to submit the form using something like this, is there something that i am missing?
If,yes, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are declaring function with `onClick` use IIF expression

```
 <a href="#" onClick="(
                 function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();  
                    document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
                 })(event) 
          ">LogOut</a>

<a href="#" onClick="(function(event){event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();})(event)">LogOut</a>
```

or don't use function expression

```
<a href="#" onClick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();">LogOut</a>
```

---

However I would **recommend** you to get rid of ugly inline click handler and don't use inline click handler in old and bad practices. You should bind event using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

*HTML*

```
<a href="#" id='logout'>LogOut</a>
```

*Script*

```
document.querySelector('#logout').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks mayne, i knew most of the steps , i just wanted to know if we could do this or not.You replied before everyonee.Hence , That tick (:

Comment: Also... one can use newlines and such in a html attribute, so you don't need to cram it all into one line... https://gist.github.com/tschallacka/19877de484a83f28c19b658f27062c52

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `on` attributes of html elements anymore. Instead use `addEventListener` like in the answer of [Satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395809/1960455)

The `onclick` is evaluated at the time you click on the link so if you really want to get this to work, you would need to write it as an immediately-invoked function expression:

```
<a href="#" onClick="(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
 })(event)">LogOut</a>
```

But you really should not do it that ways. You should always keep html, js and css separated.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<a href="#" onClick="
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
 ">LogOut</a>
```

or

```js
function sendData (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="sendData()">LogOut</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The context you are trying to use the function expression in expects the `function` keyword to start a function declaration.

A function declaration must have a name.

There is no point in putting a function there anyway: You never call it.

The value of an `onclick` attribute is the function body.

If you were going to go down this route then you code would look like this:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();"
```

**But don't do that!**

---

Intrinsic event attributes are horrible for a variety of reasons. Bind your event handlers with JavaScript.

```
<a href="#">LogOut</a>

document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
});
```

**But don't do that either!**

---

You have a link to the top of the page which you are then "enhancing" with JavaScript to submit a form.

If the JavaScript fails, it doesn't make any sense to link to the top of the page.

Before applying JavaScript: **Pick the HTML with the most appropriate semantics and default functionality**.

In this case, that means **use a submit button**.

```
<button>LogOut</button>
```

If you don't like the way it looks, apply CSS to style it the way you want.

```css
button {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button>LogOut</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you're declaring function inside `onClick` and you should call it. Define your function outside and then call it from `onClick` like `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't call a function directly that way, cause that code is trying to create a new function, not executing that function. You should create a function somewhere, and call it at the `onclick` event. For instance:

```
    function myFunction(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
    }

    <a href="#" onClick="myFunction">LogOut</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a click event directly to an HTML element, then you should use a standard method like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form id="LogOut-form" type="submit"></form>
     <a href="#" onClick="buttonClicked(event)">LogOut</a>
   </body>
   <script>
     function buttonClicked(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById('LogOut-form').submit();
     }
   </script>
</html>
```

Here, **buttonClicked()** is a function, which will invoke whenever click triggered.